# Claiming Gift Aid on conference my non-profit is organising

Tags: united-kingdom, gift, charity

My unincorporated, HMRC tax-exempt UK non-profit is working on organising a conference in the next year. For the conference, we are charging a fee for each attendee, but reinvesting all money from the tickets into the event, so there is no 'surplus benefit value', as is deemed by [this guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/charities-detailed-guidance-notes/chapter-3-gift-aid#chapter-323-valuing-donor-benefits). The aforementioned link also provides the example of tickets to an event as a potential claim to Gift Aid, but in the example doesn't clarify whether the party providing the tickets is the one operating the event.

However, [this](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/gift-aid-what-donations-charities-and-cascs-can-claim-on#charity-events) seems to imply that Gift Aid cannot be claimed for 'charity events', without detailing what counts as such an event. This event, despite being organised by our charity and all funds collected by us, is nothing to do with our charity, nor will it have our donation boxes everywhere: we'll be inviting a lot of speakers to talk about our field (education) and booths, but nothing about non-profits/us.

Can we legally claim Gift Aid on the tickets? The above two pages seem to, in my interpretation, somewhat contradict each other, but since they are just guidance, reference to a specific law would help to clarify. Further, if it is legal under some structure, how is it best to describe the money on the Gift Aid claim?